# How to use caching?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, caching

Basically, I retrieved a dataset and I want to cache it in the server memory for one month. So I don't need to call the query again and again when running the page within this month.

I did some research and think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx is the way to do the cache, basically i modified the sub codes to fit into my application

```
Public Sub RemovedCallback(k As String, v As Object, r As CacheItemRemovedReason)
    itemRemoved = True
    reason = r
End Sub
Function AddItemToCache(cacheKey as String, ds as Dataset)
    itemRemoved = False

    onRemove = New CacheItemRemovedCallback(AddressOf Me.RemovedCallback)

    If (IsNothing(Cache(cacheKey))) Then
        Cache.Add(cacheKey, ds, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.High, onRemove)
    End If
End Function
```

There are quite a few errors in this piece of code. One of the error is for `Cache(cacheKey)` says that " Cache is a type and cannot be used for expression"? where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're using IIS cache. First of all, if this is your route - if you have an assemblies that may use cache (when available), you need to create `Caching` assembly in which you check for `HTTPcontext`. If it is `null` - you are running outside of IIS and caching will not be available. 
A good alternative is to download **Enterprise Library Caching blocks** if you working with framework up to 3.5. If you use FW4.0+ you use **system.runtime.caching**. This way cache will be available always. There is also AppFaric and some third party cache implementations but this is probably outside the scope for you.

For your error, it sounds like your identifier `Cache` [your code is not showing how you assign it] is actually a type. That is if you did this

```
If Integer Is Nothing....
```

What you need is to use is syntax

```
System.Web.Caching.Cache.Add...
```

Now, this is instance. So, what you can do is

```
Dim c as Cache = System.Web.Caching.Cache
c.Add(....
```